# Can I force the first letter of the verbose_name of a django model field to be lower case?

Tags: django, django-models

Django automatically capitalizes the first letter of the verbose_name of a field in a model. I'd like it to be lower case. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Override template 'admin/index.html' and change

```
<th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></th>
```

to

```
<th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name|lower }}</a></th>
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work for the index page. Any thoughts on targeting it more specifically to one of the fields of a sub-class of models.Model?

Comment: No. They use capfirst everywhere to print verbose_name_plural.

Answer (score 1):

A workable but somewhat kludgy solution that I am going to use is to make the first character of my verbose_name strings the unicode Zero Width Space (\u200B).

Comment: This is actually a great solution.  Thank you.